# In JSTL foreach passing JSON object from JSP to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, json, jstl

In JSTL`for each` I get the JSON object like-

`[{"id":"2333","name":"sam"},{"id":"2444","name":"ram"}]`

How should I pass the JSON object to JavaScript function `onclick`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you post some code or at least pseudo-code of what you're trying to do?

Comment: <c:forEach var="jdata" iteam="${items}" varStatus="loop">                     <div  id="id${loop}"  onClick="dataGT('${jdata}','id${loop}'); ">   ..... ......                                                            </div>                                                                                                       </c:FoEach>                                                                                              jdata=[{"id":"2333","name":"sam"},"id":"2444","name":"ram"}] - javascript onClick function i need to pass the "jdata" json data to java script function